# How to send a request body like "this" in flutter HTTP post request?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to make an application in which I am basically making the app a httpClient which just takes the input from the app and then sends it to a website it then parses the webpage and displays specific text(kinda table) from it.

So for that i was using http.post(), the http request which goes through normal user interaction of browser is like this:

```
POST /example/Directory/xxx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://www.example.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Save-Data: on
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
X-Hola-Unblocker-Bext: reqid 14107: before request, send headers
X-Hola-Request-Id: 14107
```

And The Request body is:

```
date=07-01-2019
```

I've tried sending "date=07-01-2019" in 'body:' argument of http.post() i also tried using it like {'date':'07-01-2019'} in body: argument.

I even tried storing {'date':'07-01-2019'} in a variable and then using json.encode() on that but no luck.

```
timeTableFetch() async{
  String url = "http://example.com";
  var response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}, body: "date=07-01-2019");
  var document = parse(response.body);
  var timeTable = document.getElementsByTagName("gradienttable");//this is what i want

}
```

So i expected to get that timeTable variable which i was going to processed further but i can't get that i tried printing HTML of page which Shows that the  response is coming but the date which i sent isn't valid.

I've read the documentation at [DartLang](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/http/latest/) they have used body like this

```
var url = "http://example.com/whatsit/create";
http.post(url, body: {"name": "doodle", "color": "blue"});
```

but doing so in my code is still not working

Updated Code:

```
timeTableFetch() async{
  String url = "http://example.com";
  var response = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}, body: {'date': '07-01-2019'});
  var document = parse(response.body);
  var timeTable = document.getElementsByTagName("gradienttable");//this is what i want

}
```

Comment: `"I've tried sending "date=07-01-2019" in 'body:' argument of http.post() i also tried using it like {'date':'07-01-2019'} in body: argument."` - i will tell you what you haven't tried: you haven't tried to read the official `http` package documentation

Comment: I have read that before and also had a look now but couldn't get what you were referring to by this comment :(

Comment: ok then post the link to the documentation and explain whats not clear?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: ok so what is `"gradienttable"` here? what actually do you want to achieve? you posted your request to the server, right? what now?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'Content-Type: application/json' if you want to send json ? It's not clear if you are amending this if you try to send a json object. (not sure it should matter if just sending a param/datestring combination though.

Comment: I set it like this to mimic actual POST which was sent from browser it send it like this so.

Comment: and did you check `response.body`? tried to `print()` it?

Comment: Yeah the response is coming but the response is not the same which i get if is end the body "date=07-01-2019" from chrome/firefox developer tool.(so i guess the request body has some problem)